# android, NavigationView's setItemTextColor and setItemIconTinList have no effects

Tags: java, android, android-navigationview

Sorry for my english.

I need to set item text and item icon color of NavigationView dynamically, but this is not working for some reason.

It will be a bug or am I doing something wrong?
XML works well, but when I do the following things, not:

**My code:**

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        int[][] states = new int[][] {
                new int[] {  }, // default
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed },  // pressed
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected } // selected
        };

        int[] colors = new int[] {
                colorDefault,
                colorFocused,
                colorSelected
        };

        ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        navigationView.setItemTextColor(myList);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(myList);
```

For some reason, I only get the first color :(

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected } // selected               
            new int[] {  } // default
    };

int[] colors = new int[] {
        colorSelected,            
        colorDefault
};
ColorStateList colorList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
navigationView.setItemTextColor(colorList);
```

Just use only selected and the default for navigation text state. As Matei Said. You need to use in order of the most specific case.

Answer (score 0):

It's like catching exceptions: you need to start with the most specific case and then with the more general. In your case, it would be:

```
 int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected } // selected
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed },  // pressed
            new int[] {  }, // default
    };

int[] colors = new int[] {
        colorSelected,
        colorFocused,
        colorDefault
};
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but not, nothing happens :(